# Display result on web page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the result of a query in to json format and display the result in a TextField on a web page. I have a drop down list "RequestType", when a selection is made I need jQuery to lookup a value from MySQL table and return the result. So far my script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#RequestType').change(function()
     {
     var department = $(this).val();
     $.ajax(
     {
      url:"check_department.php",
      type:'post',
      data:{department:$(this).val()},
      success:function(response)
      {
        $('#Department').html(response);
      }

    });
    });
});
```

Using FireBug to see what my PHP query script is returning I get

```
{"input#Department":"Housekeeping"}
```

I am expecting "Housekeeping" but I can't seem to get the result in to a TextField on the web page. The TextField is: name="Department". id="Department".

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try $('#Department').val(response);

Comment: Hi, I have added but in FireBug I get the following error TypeError: $(...).JSON is undefined url:"check_department.php",
                    type:'post',
                    data:{department:$(this).val()},
     dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        $('#Department2').JSON.stringify(response);
                    }

Comment: Because JSON isn't jQuery function, so you can't call it on jQuery object

Comment: Hi all, I have a result by using: $('#Department2').val(response["input#Department2"].toString()). Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 0):

To your .ajax call add:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Also, you should use string version of your json object, for that you need:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(response.input#Department);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

$('#Department').html(response["input#Department"].toString())

instead of insert an object try to insert a string

Comment: Error:TypeError: response['input#Department'] is undefined when I use $('#Department').html(response["input#Department"].toString())

Comment: Hi, Using $('#Department').val(response); the textfield displays [object Object], anyone know why? again many thanks